# Check if person leaving site through mouse move

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

anybody help me 
how to check if person leaving site through mouse move toward the close button?

Thanks

Comment: beforeunload event ???

Comment: Javascript can only detect the mouse in the area where HTML is visible so trying to capture a hover event on the `X` in the upper-right (Windows) is not an option. As @A.Wolff describes, you need to listen for your page to receive the unload event.

Comment: The mouse moving out of the page doesn't necessarily mean they're leaving the page either.

Comment: you can use .unload() ( jQuery) for a crossbrowser solution : http://api.jquery.com/unload/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you might need to look at Page Visibility API ,

Page Visibility API document.hidden is one way to access whethere user is on website or not , it works on switching tab , closing browser all..

here's nice explaination on that := [Page Visibility API Info](http://blog.teamtreehouse.com/an-introduction-to-the-page-visibility-api)

notice the browser support at end.

```
IE      Firefox         Chrome      Safari  Opera
10+     10.0+           14.0+       7.0+    12.1+
```